# VBA Access get string from db

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a table with a column contain email addresses.

I would like to get these email addresses and send mail to them.
My problem is that i don't know how to get the addresses.
I would like to get a string as

```
me@email.com;me2@email.com;me3@email.com...etc
```

How can i get this string in order to pass it to the recipents?

Comment: have you tried using that string as it is?

Comment: what do you  mean?i don't know the emails that will be in the db

Comment: Is that how the strings are in you DB?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From memory (not tested):

```
Dim db As DAO.Database, rs As DAO.Recordset
Dim s As String

Set db = CurrentDb
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT email FROM myTable WHERE ...")
Do While Not rs.EOF
    If s = "" Then
        s = rs!email
    Else
        s = s & ";" & rs!email
    End If
    rs.MoveNext
Loop
rs.Close: Set rs = Nothing
db.Close: Set db = Nothing
```

---

Since concatenating strings from a query is a frequent task, I suggest creating a reusable Function:

```
Public Function ConcatenateFromSql(ByVal sql As  String, _
                                   Optional ByVal delimiter As String = ";") As String
    Dim db As DAO.Database, rs As DAO.Recordset
    Dim s As String

    Set db = CurrentDb
    Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(sql)
    Do While Not rs.EOF
        If s = "" Then
            s = rs(0)
        Else
            s = s & delimiter & rs(0)
        End If
        rs.MoveNext
    Loop
    rs.Close: Set rs = Nothing
    db.Close: Set db = Nothing

    ConcatenateFromSql = s
End Function
```