# VBA Run String as Code

Tags: vba

I want to read strings of code from a database. A string should include pieces of text and one/two variables which are set later in the project. The result should look like this:

```
"Greetings, Tom."
```

Usually I would do something like this:

```
Sub Show()
  Dim strName as String
  strName = "Tom"
  Debug.Print "Greetings, " & strName & "."
  ...
```

But in this case the part

> "Greetings, " & strName & "."

is on my database. During runtime I set the value of strName to multiple names (eg in one case to "Tom" and in another case to "Marco")

How is it possible to let VBA know that strName is a variable and not a string to be shown? In the end my call should look like this:

```
strDbText = <String from Database>
strName = "Tom"
Debug.Print strDbText '--> Greetings, Tom.
```

Can anyone help me out one more time?
Thanks a lot!

edit: 
This code will not be an executable. So there is no need to go for the VBIDE-Objects to create a new module and execute inserted code. It is a string which will be written in a Word Document.

**Solution:
String Substitution with the Replace() function**

Comment: Short answer: you can't. But -- why not just use string substitution and *replace* `"strName"` by `"Tom"`?

Comment: Look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16510800/vba-access-get-string-from-db

Comment: Why in the world would you want to execute arbitrary text as code? Do you have any concept of the damage a malevolent (or ignorant) user can inflict when you do so? For what you're describing, there is absolutely no need to *execute* anything. Store the string in the DB as `Greetings, %Name%`. At runtime, read the value *as is* from the database, and replace `%Name%` with the string containing the individual's name using normal string operations, then throw the string  into a  label's caption or wherever to show it. No *execute* involved.

Comment: Would `Debug.Print strDbText & " " & strName` not work for you?

Comment: It wont be executed directly. The fulfilled string will be written in a document. But thanks for the tip with string substitution. I'll have a look at this. 

And yes, it is kinda a repost, but trust me... I have tried every code I found here on StO.

Comment: unfortunately not because the dynamic value is in the middle of a statement. 

@JohnColeman this did the job. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would assign `strName` first and replace it with the string in the Database like this...

```
strName = "Tom"
strDbText = <String from Database>
strDbText = Replace(strDbText, "strName", strName) 'This distinguishes the string from the variable
Debug.Print strDbText '--> Greetings, Tom.
```

However, I would suggest using another variable in your database in place of `strName` because it may become confusing to look at.

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely agreeing @ShanayL answer and strongly recommending its usage, I couldn't avoid pointing an unsafe alternative to solve your question, using [Eval](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/access-vba/articles/application-eval-method-access). `Eval` is potentially dangerous, creating a code injection vulnerability in your application!!!

```
strDbText = """Greetings, "" & strName"
strName = "Tom"
Debug.Print Eval(strDbText) 'Greetings, Tom
```

Notice: `Eval` is potentially dangerous and its usage is strongly disencouraged!